# Unable to update user Roles in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Whenever I try to update the user role, it update the password automatically.

This is the `service` class:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    
    @Autowired RoleRepository roleRepo;
    
    @Autowired PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    public void registerDefaultUser(User user) {
        Role roleUser = roleRepo.findByName("User");
        user.addRole(roleUser);
        encodePassword(user);
        userRepo.save(user);
    }
    
    public List<User> listAll() {
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }

    public User get(Long id) {
        return userRepo.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    public List<Role> listRoles() {
        return roleRepo.findAll();
    }
    
    public void save(User user) {
        encodePassword(user);       
        userRepo.save(user);
    }

}
```

This is the `controller`:

```
@GetMapping("/users/edit/{id}")
public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    User user = service.get(id);
    List<Role> listRoles = service.listRoles();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("listRoles", listRoles);
    return "user_form";
}

@PostMapping("/users/save")
public String saveUser(User user) {
    user.getPassword(); 
    service.save(user);
    
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

I want to be ale to update the roles only, without changing the password the user has set.

Answer (score 0):

The password changes on save as your safe function always calls `encodePassword(user);`. you can prevent this in multiple ways.

1. Give the edit function of user a seperate endpoint from create and make an update function in service that does not call you `encodePassword(user)` function.
2. Don't use model entities in post and introduce a bean that holds all the modifiable fields of the user, than in the save function check if a new password is given and only than change the users password.

```java
public void save(UserBean userBean)
{
    User user;
    if(userBean.getId() == null)
        user = new User();
    else
        user = userRepo.findById(userBean.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("no user with id"));

    if(userBean.getPassword() != null)
    {
        user.setPassword(userBean.getPassword());
        encodePassword(user);
    }

    user.setName(userBean.getName());
    // rest of you fields to edit/set
    userRepo.save(user);
}
```